# Reading/Accessing AppData folder using HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have written **simple extensions** for IE,Firefox and Chrome which allow users to make a call to valid phone numbers on the **right click** and this is working fine. 
But I need to run this in Citrix environment and since multiple instances of the application will be running I have set some unique values in appdata folder. For that I need to read who is the current user and the appdata folder location.

Is there a way to read the complete path of the appdata folder e.g. C:\Users\<**UserName**>\AppData\Roaming. UserName will be changing based on the logged in user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no universal way of doing that. Mostly because there's obvious and considerable security concerns involved and thus you usually don't get direct access to the filesystem.

As a work-around for Chrome, you can try looking at [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging-host) (from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912056/access-local-files-using-a-google-chrome-extension)). You'd need to research similar solutions for other browsers.

Comment: Thank you replying, Lasse. I know how to do this in IE and Firefox. But IE (using **WMI**) its **very slow**; although Firefox its working fine. NPAPI is no longer supported so couldn't find a way in Chrome...many thanks the for Chrome solution.

Comment: @Vijay: No problem. Glad to help. I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer by clicking the checkmark beneath it.

Comment: Just did. Sorry for the late response.