# Modifying local files embedded in a Google Chrome Extension using JS

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been doing a lot of research and have been unable to find an answer to my exact question. I understand that having a google chrome extension that can write to local user files would be a major security breach and thankfully isn't possible. However in my extension is a .json file that is used to make a HTML webpage with links via JavaScript. The JS reads the .json file and inserts the lines of code on the html page. I am attempting to make a user interface that allows them to update and edit the .json file that is inside the extension in order to add new lines of code to the webpage, but have been unable to find anything that could make this work due to security issues. I was thinking that since the file is in the extension users should be able to modify it.

If that was confusing here is a flow of what I want to happen and where it is not working:

Works:
Users clicks on button that takes them to a webpage hosted in the extension -> when page is loaded, the javascript runs -> the JS looks at a .json file in the extension using an XMLHttpRequest, parses the data, and then inserts it into the html -> The user now see's the content that was contained in the .json file on the html page.

Doesn't work:
After this I would like to have an interface that will allow the user to edit this .json file in order to update the page as they see fit, all in the extension itself.

If it was just me using this extension I could simply use the chrome storage api's available, however this is for my team at work, who are wanting to make edits as we need. Which means we will all be editing the same .json file.

Any information regarding this would be very beneficial. Even if it's as simple as it can't be done. Either way manually editing the .json file without a simple UI is much easier than editing the html directly.

Thanks in advance!

Posts/Articles I have looked at regarding this question:

- [Access Local Files using a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21912056/access-local-files-using-a-google-chrome-extension)
- https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage
- [Local file access with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript)
- [Allow Google Chrome to use XMLHttpRequest to load a URL from a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819060/allow-google-chrome-to-use-xmlhttprequest-to-load-a-url-from-a-local-file)

Comment: Not possible since all files in an installed extension are checked by Chrome via their hashsums. An alternative solution is based on the fact that extensions can read file:// URLs directly if the user enables the corresponding checkbox in chrome://extensions page details so you can have a textbox in your extension's options UI to paste such an URL to the shared json file, then simply read it periodically using XHR/fetch.

Comment: That's what I thought. I appreciate the quick response on it! I will have to figure out another solution in that case. Thank you!